# Spark's RDD cartesian operation to local partitions

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'd like to apply the `cartesian` locally to each partition, instead of globally to the RDD. Due to some domain knowledge, I can partition my dataset in disjoint sets. I want to exploit this to minimize the number of pairs generated in the costly `cartesian` operation.

Is it possible to deconstruct the partitions of an `RDD[T]` into a `Seq[RDD[T]` of one partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the partition indices:

```scala
(0 until rdd.partitions.size).map(
  i => rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((j, iter) => if (i == j) iter else Iterator()))
```

If all you want is to compute Cartesian product over each partition you can do it directly:

```scala
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
  val vals = iter.toSeq
  for {
    i <- vals.toIterator
    j <- vals
  } yield (i, j)
})
```

Comment: iter.toSeq is going to explode memory usage, that won't work.

Comment: Then you can use the first solution. Out of curiosity - how much data do you expect per partition?

Comment: Partitions should be around 4-16G.

Comment: If data is not fetched this way from an external system it could much more efficient to filter than partition.